# Export Texture Paint as FBX with gloss effect?

Tags: texturing, uv, export, texture-painting, .fbx

I am a beginner in modeling and using Blender. I want to model basic gemstones to export and use in my Roblox game. I am wondering if I can export my mesh in Blender with the metallic (glossy) effect. My textures would look better if they were shiny. If there is a way to do this, I would appreciate a detailed answer that is understandable for beginners :)